# Keep enabled HTML element only on home page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, html5-audio

I have a wordpress website that contains an audio element so a song auto starts when someone is visiting the website. It looks like this:

```
<figure><audio controls autoplay loop src="song-path.mp3"></audio></figure>
```

This is on a custom HTML widget. I need this tag to be active only on home page though so I made this CSS:

```
audio, canvas, progress, video {
display: none;
 }

.home audio, canvas, progress, video {
display: inline-block;
}
```

With this CSS I can keep the audio active on home page and hide it from all the other pages but the song keeps playing by the hidden player.

Is there a way to completely disable or mute the song for all of the pages but home?

Thank you

Comment: Just watch what page you are on and stop the audio when the page changes from home?

Comment: CSS cannot control how element reactive. You should use Javascript or PHP to do that.

Comment: For sure I am not expecting to do it with CSS but I am not very familiar doing it with js or php. So any hint of how I could write it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont add it only on the Homepage ?

```
if ( is_front_page() ) :
    the_widget( 'play_mp3_widget' );
else :
    the_widget( 'dontplay_mp3_widget' ); //* Or do Nothing *//
endif;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is not a widget itself so I can just disable it. It is a Custom HTML widget which contains more stuff in and there is where I wrote my <figure>. By disabling the widget I will disable content I need.

Comment: then you have to split the widget into more widgets, one with your stuff and the other with the player. Then you can configure it, so the player widget only loads on front-page (or is_home() ). Its better to not load it then to hide it. Think about the loadtime of the mp3 on every page.

Answer (score 0):

I think ideally you might want to investigate only publishing your widget or PHP code on a specific page.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76959/how-to-add-a-specific-widget-to-only-1-page

However, if that's not feasible you can stop your audio with JavaScript. First, add an ID to your audio element.

```
<audio id="myAudio" controls autoplay loop src="song-path.mp3"></audio>
```

Next, add this code where needed.

```
<script>
var myHomeAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 
myHomeAudio.pause(); 
</script>
```

Update: if you go the JavaScript route, the name of the ID doesn't matter -- just take care that the ID of the element and the way you reference it in JS match. If you want to try and autodetect using the "home" slug name, this might work.

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var currentPage = pathArray[0];
if (currentPage !== "home"){ // Not equal to the Home page
  var myHomeAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 
  myHomeAudio.pause(); 
}
```

All that said, when time permits you might want to investigate the serverside model and avoid having this widget on pages where it isn't used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying this now. Should I replace myHomeAudio with something else or is this the way I should place the js? "home" is my the home page slug and this is why I wrote it like that

Comment: I went with the JS as I can edit JS on my theme including <script> tags. The song keeps playing everywhere though and not only on homepage.

As for your update, can I include it in script tags somehow?

Comment: Tested the new one too included the script tags but the song keeps playing :/